# Passing Tkinter values to Python animation

Tags: python, animation, tkinter

I am writing physics visualization tools for projectile motion which requires a user to input some numbers in a Tkinter window. After they are finished, they click the *Run* button, and an animation begins showing the results.

Here is the relevant code that I currently have (unneeded or unimportant methods not included):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from Tkinter import *

class ProjectileMotion:

    def __init__(self):
        self.params = ['mass', 'g', 'v0', 'theta']
        self.default_vals = ['1.0', '9.81', '10', '45']
        self.fields = {'mass':1.0, 'g':9.81, 'v0':10, 'theta':45}
        self.origin = (0, 0)
        self.entries = []
        self.dt = 0.01
        self.time_elapsed = 0
        self.state = []


    def store_values_in_dictionary(self):
        for entry in self.entries:
            field = entry[0]
            value  = entry[1].get()
            self.fields[field] = value



    def setValues(self):
        for key in self.fields:
            try:
                self.fields[key] = float(self.fields[key])
                if (key == "g"):
                    # make sure "g" is < 0
                    self.fields[key] = -np.abs(self.fields[key])

            except ValueError:
                print "Error: You must enter a number for field: ",key.upper()
                abort()

        # define initial state
        vels = self.getComponentVelocities()
        self.state = [0.0, vels[0], 0.0, vels[1]]


    def getComponentPositions(self):
        """return current x,y positions of the projectile"""
        x = self.state[0]
        y = self.state[2]
        return (x, y)


    def getComponentVelocities(self):
        """compute the current x,y velocities of the projectile"""
        v0x = self.fields['v0']*np.cos(self.fields['theta']*np.pi/180.)
        v0y = self.fields['v0']*np.sin(self.fields['theta']*np.pi/180.)
        return (v0x, v0y)


    def getTimeVec(self):
        timeVec = np.arange(0,self.totalTime(),self.dt)
        return timeVec


    def maxHeight(self):
        """Get max height of projectile"""
        vels = self.getComponentVelocities()
        return 0.5*(vels[1]*vels[1])/np.abs(self.fields['g'])


    def maxRange(self):
        """Get max range of projectile"""
        vels = self.getComponentVelocities()
        return (2.0*vels[0]*vels[1])/np.abs(self.fields['g'])


    def totalTime(self):
        vels = self.getComponentVelocities()
        return (2.0*vels[1])/np.abs(self.fields['g'])



    def step(self):
        """execute one time step of length dt and update state"""
        # x-direction
        self.state[0] += self.state[1]*self.dt
        self.state[1] = self.state[1]

        # y-direction
        self.state[2] += self.state[3]*self.dt + 0.5*self.fields['g']*self.dt*self.dt
        self.state[3] += self.fields['g']*self.dt

        # advance time
        self.time_elapsed += self.dt

##########################################################
""" RUN SIM """
##########################################################

pm = ProjectileMotion()
root = Tk()

counter = 0
for param in pm.params:
    row = Frame(root)
    label = Label(row, width=15, text=param, anchor='w')
    entry = Entry(row)
    entry.insert(END, pm.default_vals[counter])

    row.bind()
    row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
    label.pack(side=LEFT)
    entry.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)

    (pm.entries).append((param, entry))
    counter += 1

# bind a key to root so we store values we choose
root.bind('<Key>', (lambda event: pm.store_values_in_dictionary()))

# set up buttons to run
b1 = Button(root, text='Run', command=root.destroy)
b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)


def runStuff():
    # run the window to get user commands
    root.mainloop()
    # once user hits *Run* button, take values and
    # load into projectile motion object
    pm.setValues()


# run everything and then set values when user done
runStuff()

# set up figure and animation
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'o')
plt.xlim(0, pm.maxRange()+2)
plt.ylim(0, pm.maxHeight()+2)

def animate(i):
    # advance particle to next time step
    pm.step()
    line.set_data(*pm.getComponentPositions()) 
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=pm.getTimeVec(),
                        interval=3000*pm.dt, blit=True, repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

In order for the animation to play, the user has to click the *Run* button which actually calls `root.destroy` in order to advance to setting up the movie etc.

What I would like to do is have the *Run* button call a method called `runAnimation` which then executes everything after the RUN SIM comment. This seems less kludgey.

The problem I have is, after many failed attempts which are not shown here for brevity, what does `runAnimation` look like, where does it live, what inputs does it have etc. since it depends on values supplied by the user which have not been displayed since `root.mainloop()` wouldn't have been called yet.

Ideas would be very appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to destroy root to get the animation to work. Destroying root sounds like a bad idea to me if you are using tkinter to run your program.

Comment: I agree -- hence the question. But it's the only method that's worked so far and I don't think it's the optimal way to do this.

Comment: You do not need to destroy the window. Just need to have the run button activate a function that will perform the task you need it to. So move all the code that executes after root.destroy() into the program as a function instead.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. I could have sworn I tried that and it didn't work, but thanks for the suggestion and I'll let you know.